# Eval not working with String from Excel

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to execute code read from an Excel workbook. For some reason the following code does not actually evaluate, however.

```
import win32com.client
import os

excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
local_dir = os.getcwd()
book = excel.Workbooks.Open(local_dir+'\\Condition.xlsx', True)
sheet = book.Sheets('Sheet1')

condition = sheet.Cells(1,3).Value

print condition
print eval(condition)

excel.Workbooks.Close()
```

If the cell in question contains "1+2", the above code just prints out "1+2", not "3". If I replace "condition" with "1+2", it evaluates correctly. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: does the string itself contain quotes? That is likely the problem... Try `eval(condition.strip('"')`

Comment: Your cell contains the string `"1+2"`, quotes included,  which evaluates as this string. And beware of `eval`...

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks! I'm not sure how else to do what I need to do other than use eval. I need to enable the user to define a logic expression that has no pre-defined form or structure, and it will require API calls, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you using `eval()` because it can be [very dangerous and harmful to your code's security](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Instead of that i recommend you using `literal_eval` from `ast` module:

```
from ast import literal_eval as eval
# work to do ...
```

So, an easy fix to your code in order to handle strings with quotes like `"1+3"` and others, you can do something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval as eval
# your actual code
# ...
print(eval(condition.replace('"', '')))
# Or
# print(eval(condition.strip('"')))
```

Edit:

The difference between `eval()` and `literal_eval()`:

- `eval(my_string_or_input)`: evaluates the code
  (string/input/raw_input) as soon as the function is called without
  checking if the code in the argument is safe or not.
- `literal_eval(my_string_or_input)`: will raise an exception if the
  string/input/raw_input in the argument isn't a valid Python code. So,
  it will not be excecuted if there is an unsafe code.

You can check this [question/answers in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) for more explanations.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between eval and ast.literal_eval?

Comment: There's more to it than that. literal_eval only allows a certain subset of python syntax, and it does not allow you to grab global and local dictionaries from the evaluation (a feature I actually need).

Comment: So, be aware while using `eval()`. You know what you're facing :-)